# Creating a wiping effect using overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have finished creating my website and are going to start creating animations for it. I fell in love with this sites animation, https://www.aristidebenoist.com/ , and are trying to recreate it. Anybody know the basis for this effect, and how to go about creating it?

Comment: You can hire me to create this. And do not post question of this type, its like you ask somebody create the whole complicated thing for free.

Comment: Hey mate, can you show us any coding you have already tried to achieve the effect?

Comment: Alright, my bad. Im kind of new to coding and to this website. Found out a way to do it by myself, but not really sure if thats the most effecient way of doing so. Going to create a new post where i show my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking out the elements in the console, it looks like the developer wrapped his inline elements with a `span` within a `span` and gave it a transform/animation property.

You could achieve the same by applying a class that has a transition or animation once the screen has been scrolled to a certain point.

Here is a pen to checkout : https://codepen.io/matt6frey/pen/dwKWMg

Hope that helps out. Cheers!